# What is best option for dealing with date types in Android?

Tags: java, android, date, android-studio

What is at the moment best option for dealing with date in time in Android development, since Android studio doesn't yet support Java 8 (and new java.time package) (if I am correct)?

Comment: It does support Java 8. Well at least some of it.

Comment: You could use the [ThreeTen backport](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp).

Comment: Maybe http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Support for Java 8 language features requires a new compiler called
   Jack. Jack is supported only on Android Studio 2.1 and higher. So if
   you want to use Java 8 language features, you need to use Android
   Studio 2.1 to build your app. Source: developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html
2. For date's and Timestamp you can see the links given below: using [java.util.Date]https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html Or By using [java.text.SimpleDateFormat] https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

- [**ThreeTenABP**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)

  - [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

### Java 6 & 7

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

### Android: *ThreeTenABP*

That back-port is further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [**ThreeTenABP**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

You should definitely avoid the troublesome confusing mess that is the legacy date-time classes.